# is there any way to plot a list using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

As a beginner, I am working with plotting using sympy. Is there any way that I can plot a graph using a simple list?

```
from sympy.plotting import plot
y_vals = [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: def make_graph(y_vals):
    return sp.plot(y_vals)

Comment: This kind of plotting is trivial with `matplotlib`

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented way to do that.

First, you need to create a `List2DSeries` series objects containing the coordinates; then instantiate the `Plot` class to create the plot.

```
from sympy.plotting.plot import List2DSeries, Plot
x_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_vals = [1, 4, 9, 16]
s = List2DSeries(x_vals, y_vals)
Plot(s).show()
```

Comment: its throwing me this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\suman\PycharmProjects\pendings\andrea\Andrea LAB 10.py", line 75, in <module>
    Plot(s).show()
  File "C:\Users\suman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py", line 240, in show
    self._backend.show()
  File "C:\Users\suman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py", line 1562, in show
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The TextBackend supports only expressions over a 1D range

Comment: try to execute `Plot(s, backend="matplotlib").show()`. Do you have matplotlib installed?